# Correct usage of branching in git

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get better in my usage of git. In using branches, there are a few steps that confuse me:

```
git branch my-new-branch
git checkout my-new-branch
... make changes ...
git add .
git commit -m "my changes"
git push origin my-new-branch
```

Now my remote new branch is up to date, and I want to merge it into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge my-new-branch
```

This seems to bring my local master up to date, but now my remote. What's the correct next step? Doing

```
git push
```

seems to do the trick... Is that ok?

Finally, I want to delete the `my-new-branch` branch.

```
git branch -d my-new-branch
```

Again, things look ok locally, but not on my remote. How do I get the remote up to date now?

Is this generally the right way to go about this? Some steps smell off to me...

Comment: What's the problem with your remote? Also you can create the branch and check it out in one command. `git checkout -b my-new-branch`

Comment: Since you tagged with github: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-the-automatic-deletion-of-branches

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)